# Dr Rudi (super alpha) hops NZ, experiences?

Tags: hops

Last night a friend at our brewing space passed me a new bag of Dr. Rudi Hops and said "we just got this in would you like to try it in your brew this evening?" I of course said yes.

Only now do I think to ask has anyone here used this hop before?

how: bittering, flavor, aroma?

And most importantly... What was it like?

It said 11.7% AA on the pack, but I only used it for aroma.

Comment: Update for you - I just cracked open a bottle of my latest using these hops. A DIPA with Dr Rudi, Summit and Glacier. It's unreal. The Candy/Bubblegum aroma is so pronounced. Very pleased!

Comment: My brew got an infection, so I will have to wait a while. Glad yours came out well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://hopunion.com/new-zealand-dr.-rudi/

I've used before as flavour (with great results using extract) but it's dual purpose. Why not try a SMASH (Single Malt And Single Hop) beer with a neutral yeast!

Answer (score 1):

Finally getting round to reporting back on this, only 2 years and many brews later.

I find it fruity and full of flavour, slight hints of pine but rich dark fruits with a touch of citrus. I am absolutely sold on this hop for both bittering and aroma.